# Filtering dates in PivotTable = nightmare. Code works sometimes, and sometimes not

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a lot of troubles with a filter in a Pivot Table. The only way I found to succeed so far is to remove any blank in my list of data by adding dummy dates. Once I have only one type of data in the source range for the Pivot Table I can do a pivotfields.numberformat on number ("0.00"), then the filter works and I can put the data back in "dd/mm/yyyy".

I know it is possible to use this method (pivotitem.visible = true / false) with blank in the source range but I do not succeed.

Here are two files, same data, same pivot table, same code. One works and the other not. If I can find out why it might help me to understand the problem better.

Code that works:

http://cjoint.com/14sp/DIExZVpRxgC.htm

Code that does not work:

http://cjoint.com/14sp/DIEx0ru5BgM.htm

In advance, thanks for your help

Tweedi

Answer (score 0):

Back to my initial file, I managed to do some progress. Please find my file here:
http://cjoint.com/14oc/DJbb2yqJ5XQ.htm

I managed to be able to apply the PivotItem.Visible property on "(blank)" by adding this to the code:

```
mytable.ManualUpdate = True
Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("date closed")
pf.AutoSort xlManual, pf.SourceName
```

Now when it comes to compare the other dates with the max date, it does not work and I think it is because it compares a dd/mm/yyyy with a mm/dd/yyyy (I am not sure but please look at the printscreen): http://i62.tinypic.com/wv7o9l.jpg

Any help ? Thanks !

Tweedi